# How do I configure vsftpd and openssl to avoid TLS unsupported protocol error with Sony Camera

Tags: ssl, openssl, ftp, ftps, vsftpd

I have a Sony a7iii camera that I'm trying to connect to a self-hosted vsftpd server. Connection works fine in FTP (unencrypted) mode but fails when I switch to encrypted mode per the log readout below. Have already followed the guide to prepare the camera from [Sony's website](https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1720/v1/en/contents/TP0001666505.html). Server is running Debian 10 with vsftpd 3.0.3 and openssl 1.1.1d. Connection from FileZilla on a different client works fine.

#### vsftpd.log

```
Mon Dec 14 23:54:20 2020 [pid 465] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:192.168.40.92"
Mon Dec 14 23:54:20 2020 [pid 465] FTP response: Client "::ffff:192.168.40.92", "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)"
Mon Dec 14 23:54:20 2020 [pid 465] FTP command: Client "::ffff:192.168.40.92", "AUTH TLS"
Mon Dec 14 23:54:20 2020 [pid 465] FTP response: Client "::ffff:192.168.40.92", "234 Proceed with negotiation."
Mon Dec 14 23:54:20 2020 [pid 465] DEBUG: Client "::ffff:192.168.40.92", "SSL_accept failed: error:14209102:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol"
```

#### vsftpd.conf

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
log_ftp_protocol=YES
debug_ssl=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH:AES256-SHA:!aNULL
ssl_tlsv1=YES

local_root=(removed)

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=3050
pasv_min_port=3000
```

I found a Reddit user with a [similar problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/SonyAlpha/comments/8xfrin/i_cant_get_ftps_to_work_on_my_a7_iii_any/) but implementing his solution of adding `ssl_ciphers` to the config does not seem to fix this for me.

When I do a tcpdump on the server and import into Wireshark I see a Client Hello followed by a fatal error response due to protocol version:

#### Wireshark [camera --> vsftpd]: TLSv1 Client Hello

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 66
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 62
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Random: cf73dfbf790af4cee34aba8c0b4f4b00db4f7e14eb06ceebd8278c874e0abf6a
        Session ID Length: 0
        Cipher Suites Length: 16
        Cipher Suites (8 suites)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0038)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
            Compression Method: null (0)
        Extensions Length: 5
        Extension: heartbeat (len=1)
            Type: heartbeat (15)
            Length: 1
            Mode: Peer allowed to send requests (1)
```

#### Wireshark [vsftpd --> camera]: TLSv1 Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Protocol Version)

```
TLSv1 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Protocol Version)
    Content Type: Alert (21)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 2
    Alert Message
        Level: Fatal (2)
        Description: Protocol Version (70)
```

#### Result of `openssl ciphers -v -tls1`

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
AES128-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
AES256-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384   TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA TLSv1 Kx=ECDHEPSK Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=SRP      Au=SRP  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256   TLSv1 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
```

How can I get past this error? Am I missing something? I see AES256-SHA listed among other common ciphers that could be negotiated. TLS 1.0 is enabled and referenced in both the Client Hello and the server response. I don't understand why I'm having this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssl_ciphers=HIGH:AES256-SHA:!aNULL
```

By default Debian 10 uses the security level 2 which disables TLS 1.0. Try to set the ciphers to 'HIGH:@SECLEVEL=1' in order to allow TLS 1.0.

Comment: I was not aware that Debian 10 dropped support for TLS 1.0. Unfortunately, changing this setting in the vsftpd config file doesn't work, but I was able to get it working by editing `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` to change `MinProtocol` from `TLSv1.2` to `TLSv1.0`. Don't know how I missed this. Thank you so much for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: @rapido_edwardo: The support was not **dropped** but it was disabled **by default**.